# the different ways of declaring javascript objects - difference?

Tags: javascript, object

Im having trouble with the different ways for declaring js-objects, especially after reading the knockout.js documentation. They seem to mix all possible ways. What is the big difference between these four ways of declaring an object?

```
var object = new Object();
name.field = bla;
name.method = function() { bla };

var object = {
field : "bla",
method : function() { bla };
}
```

--> I guess these are equivalent, just different notations. But in the second case, how would you pass parameters? Or isnt it possible at all?

And in the two bwlo: Whats the difference between storing it in a variable and not storing it in a variable (other than the way the object would be passed to a function)?

```
function object() {
this.field = "bla";
this.method = function() { bla };
}

otherfunction(new Object());

var myobject = function name() {
this.field = "bla";
this.method = function() { bla };
}

otherfunction(new myobject());
otherfunction(myobjet);
```

EDIT: Sorry for asking again, didn't see the other one in the suggested topics.

Comment: What do you mean by "how would you pass parameters"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one you are using new statement:

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

So you can make an object of any function you define

```
var x = function() {};
new x();
```

The second thing is an object literal:

> An object literal is a list of zero or more pairs of property names and associated values of an object, enclosed in curly braces ({}).

It's always an instance of an Object function. Why would you like to to pass parameters here? You are defining explicit object, there is no need to pass parameters here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I get the part about passing parameters, now.